# What is the quiescent voltage of this circuit?

Tags: current, jfet

I am struggling to understand how the voltage on the capacitor C18 and at the gate of Q2 normalises to a quiescent state in the below circuit:

[image]

Specifically, I have two questions:

When the circuit is initialised, the output of the comparator will be high, and the upper current mirror will charge the capacitor until D6 is reverse biased, but at what point does this happen? Current will flow out the emitter of Q5 but there is no resistance to create a voltage, so what stops the capacitor from charging infinitely?

Secondly, when the circuit is initialised there'll be zero volts on the positive side of the capacitor, but won't this cause the gate of Q2 to be way higher than the source, thus damaging it? I know that the source of Q2 will be above -V due to R34, but not at zero volts?

Comment: It might help if you [edit] to explain what the circuit is supposed to do and to credit the circuit's designer / owner as required by site policy.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what else this is connected to, but "attack" and "decay" sounds like an envelope generator for analog synth.  Though it seems to be free-running here, not gated by something else, which seems weird.  But it does depend on the other connections.

First, assume comparator +IN = GND, and -IN < GND, so output is high.  Also assume C18 is somewhat negative (this will become obvious in a moment).  I'm also assuming +/-V is around +/-12V, but could be anywhere from 5 to 18 depending.

C18 charges as described.  Q2 is a source follower, which draws extremely low current from C18, buffering its voltage (and adding an offset; probably the source voltage is 0-2V higher, depending on Q2 -- JFETs have wide manufacturing variation).  Thus, a feedback voltage to -IN comes from the capacitor, which is slowly charging, until the feedback reaches V(+IN).

When C18 charges sufficiently, the comparator flips, and now it discharges; the same thing applies again.  It seems to be an astable multivibrator.

Beware the trap of procedural thinking: it may oscillate, but at what frequency and amplitude?  In this case, there's no positive feedback (hysteresis), so the comparator likely oscillates at a frequency somewhat less than its maximum rate (under ~3MHz), and this dithers the capacitor voltage only very slightly (due to the current sources, it can't dis/charge very fast at all), so the amplitude will be small: some ~mV.  Likely nothing noticeable in the greater circuit.

It could even be stable; there are unusual conditions under which a comparator can be stable (linear operation).  Because the response is so fast, at high frequencies, it normally just flips out oscillating; if the feedback can be slowed, or attenuated substantially, it may settle into a stable response.  That may well be the case here, with the quite gentle filtering of C18.

I would still recommend an op-amp in this location, perhaps a TL072; its output will saturate cleanly near +/-V (more than enough to work the diode gate), and its output swings fast enough (a few µs) that you'll never notice it here.  (Whereas the direct relative of the LM393, the LM358 dual op-amp, is rather slow, and poor performing anyway, perhaps enough that it would actually be noticeable here -- but it would likely be fine as well.)

Another advantage to TL072 is, with a JFET input stage but low offset voltage (a few mV), one could be used to replace the JFET follower, saving a component.  (Probably the other half LM393 is used elsewhere on the larger schematic, wherever that is.)

Motifs to note:

1. **Diode gate (D6-D9)**

   The output (voltage at C18) follows the input (voltage at comparator output), with low offset, in the steady state: when everything's settled, currents (from Q5 into Q3) distribute evenly between the diodes (which need matched Vf for this use case).  When the currents are turned off, the input and output are independent.  This can be used for audio muting, RF mixing, sample-and-hold, etc.

   This also serves as a current limiter, since the output current can never be more than the bias currents.  Classic Tektronix sampling oscilloscopes used both the sampling and limiting functionalities of this arrangement.
2. **Slew rate limiter (D6-D9, C18)**

   With limited bias current into the diode gate, and a capacitor at its output, the rise/fall rate is limited to \$\frac{dV}{dt} = \frac{I}{C}\$.  If the input is a square wave for example, the output will be a trapezoidal wave (flat top/bottom, sloped rise/fall).

   This is the intended functionality here, I think.
3. **Current mirror (Q4, Q5, Q9; Q1, Q3, Q7)**

   This is a [buffered current mirror](https://wiki.analog.com/university/courses/electronics/text/chapter-11#buffered_feedback_current_mirror).  These are complementary so I will describe one, and the other is simply flipped.

   R38 sets an initial bias current, which slightly turns on Q7, then Q1 in turn.  Q1 slightly turns off Q7, so that from Q1 emitter, Q1 base will be at 1×V<sub>BE</sub>, and Q1 collector will be at 2×V<sub>BE</sub>.  Q1 V<sub>BE</sub> is what we are interested in here: this acts as a pre-biased diode, compensating for the tempco of Q3's V<sub>BE</sub>.

   Q3 and Q1 V<sub>BE</sub>s are wired in parallel, so that by e.g. the Ebers-Moll equation, Q3 collector current equals R38's current (assuming matched transistors and temperatures!).  Thus, it's a current mirror.

   To make it adjustable, rather than feeding in additional current in parallel with R38, the designer here chose to directly offset the V<sub>BE</sub> voltage: VR2, R73 and R71 form a variable voltage divider, whose voltage adds with Q1 V<sub>BE</sub>.  In this way, R38 sets the minimum current (maximum attack time), and Q3's V<sub>BE</sub> can be raised linearly -- increasing I<sub>C</sub> exponentially -- giving an exponential response from 15ms to 0.15ms, evidently.

   Finally, the buffered current mirror: if Q3 hFE were very large, this wouldn't be necessary; however, Q7 supplies the difference, so that Q1 stays at largely the same current (and thus voltage drop -- it's merely providing temperature compensation), thus allowing Q3 to be varied over several decades of collector current, with just a few transistors and resistors.